# Difference between $P(f(x*,w)>0)→1,P(f(x,w)>0)→1$ and $P(min(f(x*,w),f(x,w))>0)→1$ when dimension grows

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random-functions

Let $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n,w)$ be a function from $R^{n+1}\rightarrow R$, where $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ are deterministic variables, and $w$ be random variable. As a simple example, $f$ can be $(x_1+\cdots+x_n)w$. For simplicity, I would just write $f(\vec x,w)$ in the following context.

Is there any difference between the following two?

(1) $P(f(\vec x^*,w)>0)\rightarrow 1$ and $P(f(\vec x,w)>0)\rightarrow 1$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

(2) $P\big(\min(f(\vec x^*,w),f(\vec x,w))>0\big)\rightarrow 1$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

I encountered this question while attempting to prove a random function $f(\vec x,w)$ is positive with high probability (probability of $f>0$ goes to 1), where $\vec x\in A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a variable (deterministic), and $w$ is a random variable.

Initially, I began by proving $P(\inf_{\vec x\in A} f(\vec x,w))\rightarrow 1$ using an $\epsilon$-net argument, as the region $A$ is not discrete. However, I recently realized that, for any $x\in A$, the probability $P(f(\vec x,w))>0\rightarrow 1$. Therefore, it seems unnecessary to go through the effort of proving $P(\inf_{\vec x\in A} f(\vec x,w))\rightarrow 1$ since I already know that the function is positive at all points with high probability.

I am uncertain about which statement I should focus on proving. I am also confused on when should we use epsilon net argument. Consequently, I am curious to determine the precise distinction between (1) and (2).

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: What is P(x_1>0)?

Comment: @AndrewZhang sorry for the confusion. I've re-edited

Answer (score 0):

You have sequences of random variables $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ and you are wondering whether

(1) $P(X_n > 0) \to 1$ and $P(Y_n > 0) \to 1$

and

(2) $P(\min(X_n,Y_n)>0) \to 1$

are equivalent. The answer is **yes.**

*Proof.* Note that $\min(X_n, Y_n) \leq X_n$ and $\min(X_n, Y_n) \leq Y_n,$ so $P(\min(X_n, Y_n) > 0) \leq P(X_n > 0)$ and $P(\min(X_n, Y_n) > 0) \leq P(Y_n > 0).$ This shows (2) implies (1).

Suppose now (1) and let $\varepsilon \in (0, 1).$ Then, with probability at least $1-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},$ there exists an $N$ such that for every $n > N,$ the events $\{X_n > 0\}$ and $\{Y_n > 0\}$ have probabilities at least $1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$ If $A$ and $B$ are events, then the inclusion-exclusion formula shows that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) \geq P(A) + P(B) - 1.$ Then, $P(\min(X_n, Y_n)>0) = P(\{X_n > 0\} \cap \{Y_n > 0\}) \geq 1 - \varepsilon,$ for $n \geq N.$ Thus, (2) follows. QED

The above proof can easily be extended (by induction say), to the case of a finite number of sequences but it will fail for infinitely many sequences.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. In my case since $A$ is a connected subset in $R^{n+1}$, we have infinite many sequences. Thus this proof won't imply my case. But I was wondering whether we need the $w$ in $f(x^*,w)$ and the $w$ in $f(x,w)$ to be independent?

Comment: $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ are assumed any sequences.

Comment: And are (1) (2) equivalent in infinite case?

Comment: @happyle they shouldn't be. $\{ \min_{t\in [a,b]} X_t > 0\} \subset \bigcap_{t \in [a,b]} \{X_t > 0\}$ but the two sets might differ. However, you are using nets, so likely you have finitely many points in your net.

Comment: why $\{\min_{t\in[a,b]}X_t>0\}\subset\cap_{t\in[a,b]}\{X_t>0\}$? sorry it might be very basic. Shouldn't they be equivalent? If $X_t>0$ on every $t$ then the minimum of them must $>0$ as well.

Comment: If we assume the process is continuous, sure for an interval $[a,b].$ However, for a discontinuous process or a process that is evaluated on an open interval, then no. Consider the deterministic case of $\inf \frac{1}{t} = 0$ for $t > 0.$

Comment: If $A$ is not the case of discontinuous and open interval, we can say (1)(2) are equivalent right? how could we prove it? Maybe I should look into measure theory and real analysis?

Comment: If you want to ask a different question, do so in a new post, but don't change the current question. If $A$ is precompact (i.e. its closure is compact), then you are likely to find an $\varepsilon$-net where $f$ (assumed continuous) varies very little. In that case, you can use that (1) and (2) are equivalent since the net will be finite. It is quite hard to help you since you asked a question but you had another in mind.

Comment: I didn't change the question. the two paragraphs under (1)(2) already says $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and connected. also, my question is not 'whether (1)(2) are equivalent when $x$ belongs in $\epsilon$-net of $A$' but 'all values in $A$'.

Comment: And I already answered you. There is no difference when finitely many sequences are considered. With infinitely many sequences there will be a difference. You can easily construct an example.

Comment: by 'finite sequences' you mean $x$ takes finite values right? so, instead of two sequences $X_n,Y_n$, now we have $X^1_n,X^2_n,\cdots$. Since $A$ has infinite points, instead of $\min\{X_n,Y_n\}$ we have the infimum over infinite sequences. And in your answer you mention that the proof cannot be extended to infinite number of sequences.

Comment: Yes, correct. Because the infimum of positive numbers over an infinite set can be zero. Some exceptions apply such as continuity and compactness but if you don't have that, you need to reconsider the approach or prove it ad-hoc (i.e. prove it case by case).

Comment: so I was wondering for the infinite sequences, in the case of continuity and compactness (such that the example like $\inf 1/t$ is not included), how to prove (1) and (2) are equivalent? this should answer my original question. thanks.

Comment: Open a new post; don't ask two different questions in the same post.